# Custome admin tab in Spree but it can't be selected

Tags: spree

I am using **spree** and add a customize tab with **Deface** like 'announcement', code like this:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/admin/shared/_menu",
                 :name => "admin_annoucement_tab",
                 :insert_top => '[data-hook="admin_tabs"]') do
                    "<% if can? :admin, Spree::Announcement %>
                    <%= tab(:announcement, :url => admin_announcements_path, :icon => 'icon-bullhorn') %>
                  <% end %>"
                end
```

but when click the `Announcement` tab, page is redirect correct, but the tab is not selected.

I have saw the source code of `navigation_helper`:

```
selected = if options[:match_path]
  request.fullpath.starts_with?("#{admin_path}#{options[:match_path]}")
else
  args.include?(controller.controller_name.to_sym)
end
```

but i dont't know what `match_path` is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`match_path` is an option passed as argument to `tab` method, as you can see in code you attached this is the part of url after `admin_path` which means specified tab is selected. I'll give you an example from one of my apps:

```
 <%= tab :bundles, match_path: '/promotions' %>
```

I haven't modified `admin_path`, so if admin will visit `http://mydomain.com/admin/promotions` tab `bundles` will be checked. You haven't attached your routes so I can't write what you should specify there, but you should put there anything that comes after `admin/` part of that tab's url.

Comment: Can you help me another question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935196/use-nesting-routes-in-spree